# MongoDB how do I get the schema from schemaless?

Tags: php, json, mongodb

I am recieving a JSON object into mongodb

```
$instagram->setAccessToken($_SESSION['InstagramAccessToken']);
$popular = $instagram->getPopularMedia();
var_dump($popular);
$conn = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost/?w=1');
$db = $conn->instagram;
$collection = $db->instagram1;
$collection->insert($popular);
```

No errors and I can see the data in the collection

But when I google how to see the layout, the samples given don't seem to work for me.

```
var myvar = db.instagram1.findOne();
for (var key in myvar){print (key);}
_id
foo
bar
```

[mongo session output](https://bpaste.net/show/72096421acf3)

I am a mongo n00b (mysql defector)

[var_dump() output (raw object data)](http://paste.ee/p/hujaP)

how do I get a printout of the column headings and attributes associated with my imported JSON data? (the schema for the schemaless?)

Comment: What do you mean with "column headings" and "attributes"? What output exactly would you expect?

Comment: @Philipp  first row? Keys? Something to call on to 'get the rest'?

Comment: The code you posted prints out the keys of the first document in the collection. What other information do you need exactly?

Comment: Or to try out another angle to figure out what exactly you are asking: Why do you need to know this? What's the goal you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB schemaless aspect means that your data is also your "schema". 
 That said the collection schema may change from one document to another.

I did not tested it myself but this might help [collection schema](http://blog.optimal.io/how-to-find-the-schema-of-a-collection-in-mongodb/)

Comment: @zerospace that's the exact same code I have posted. No result.